# How to add multiple identifierURIs from Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-app-configuration, azure-identity, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to add multiple identifierURIs from Powershell.

Normally I use this command to add single identifierURI:

```
Set-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "My App" -IdentifierURIs "api://$appId"
```

What more to include in that command to add multiple identifierURIs from Powershell?

Comment: Not tested, but I would assume: `... -IdentifierURIs "api://$appId1", "api://$appId2"`

Comment: Should work, but since the description of [IdentifierUris](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/set-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0#-identifieruris) is ``<System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]>]``, you might need to cast to `[string[]]`